# Inserting data into mySQL table from mutlidimensional input form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

I wonder what's the best way to insert data into a database from a multidimensional form. The name of my form inputs is something like below:

```
name="order[][quantity]"
name="order[][description]"
name="order[][article]"
name="order[][price]"
name="order[][tax]"
name="order[][discount]"
```

How to insert this data into my database? Below is a image of my form:

[image]

As you can see the user can add many sections and all are to be handled by one submit button. Number of orders is a variable.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: name inputs must be unique, not sure this is right approach `name="order[][quantity]"` but this is `name="quantity[]"`

Comment: show some code. We like to beat things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm assuming is..

### **SomePage.php**

```
<input type='text' name='quantity[]'>
<input type='text' name='description[]'>
<input type='text' name='article[]'>
<input type='text' name='price[]'>
<input type='text' name='tax[]'>
<input type='text' name='discount[]'>
```

**Submit_Some_Page.php**

```
<?
extract($_POST);

$TotalArticle=sizeof($article);

for($i=0;$i<$TotalArticle;$i++)
{
    $Article=$article[$i];
    $Quanity=$quantity[$i];
    $Price=$price[$i];
    $Tax=$tax[$i];
    $Discount=$discount[$i];
    $Description=$description[$i];

    <-- Now, Write Insert Query Here..
    $Query="INSERT INTO TableName SET Col1Name=$Article,Col2Name=$Quanity,Col3Name=$Price,Col4Name=$Tax,Col5Name=$Discount,Col6Name=$Description";
      ..... Write Mysql Query To Execute It
}
?>
```

Comment: ohhh thank you. Exactly what I was looking for but I'm so tired today that I cant think :D

Comment: I'm Thankful To You @mrjasmin. Atleast, My Code Helped Someone. No Problem.. Sometimes, It Happen. Take Care.

Comment: Sorry To Say Mr @dlporter98 It Will Work. I Never Post Any Answer Without Proper Testing. The Person Who Asked Agreed On My Answer. And, What Validation He Has To Do, Let Him Do. As you can see the above image.. Price, Tax and discount are inter-related.. after filling those textbox only TOTAL PRICE is getting calculated. And, Thanku For downvoting my answer without testing properly.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to define the array for PHP to follow. In other words, you can't use an empty key for this, you'll need to autonumber them

```
name="order[0][quantity]"
name="order[0][description]"
name="order[0][article]"
name="order[0][price]"
name="order[0][tax]"
name="order[0][discount]"
```

And then do `order[1]` etc

Comment: This is the right way to go. The excepted answer will cause bugs