# INSERT from checkboxes to MySQL - foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql

In the folowing code I am doing an insert from a form into a mysql table

The form fields are populated from an MySQL database, which work correctly.

The problem is extracting data from the multiple checkboxes and inserting each value as a new row in the same table 'selection' columns userid and videoid.

The userid field is inserted correctly, but the videoid is not posting any data.

```
     <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username",           "$password","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");//connection string  
    $user=$_POST['userid']; 
    $checkbox1=$_POST['videoid'];  
    $chk="";  

    foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
       {  
          $chk .= $chk1.",";  
       }   
    $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl_selection (userid, videoid) VALUES ('$user', '$chk');");  
    if($in_ch==1)  
       {  
          echo'<script>alert("Inserted Successfully")</script>';  
       }  
    else  
       {  
          echo'<script>alert("Failed To Insert")</script>';  
       }  
    }  
    ?>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

This is the html form which is populated from a mysql table:

```
 <?php
    connect to database
    ?>
    <div class="control-group">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM video";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <div class="controls"> 
        <label class="checkbox"> 
          <input type="checkbox" name="videoid" value="<?php echo $line[id]?>"><?php echo $line[title]?> 
        </label> 
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You only need to connect to the database ONCE per script. That is quite a time consuming process

Comment: ...or mysqli_ if you must be old skool

Comment: Any idea as to why the foreach statement might not be working.

Comment: what do you get in $_POST['videoid']?  what values?

Comment: I have tested with - echo ("<p> your chosen video is $checkbox1</p>"); - which returns a value, but the value is not being inserted correctly. The problem must be in the **foreach** statement.

Comment: Please print the output of $chk so that we can see the values.

Comment: $chk returns a blank.

Comment: thats the problem :) please post the html that you have for the form

Comment: Just updated the post, to show the content of the html form. The checkboxes are populated from a mysql table, which is working ok as it displays all of the checkboxes on screen.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Change

```
<input type="checkbox" name="videoid" value="<?php echo $line[id]?>"><?php echo $line['title']?>
```

To

```
<input type="checkbox" name="videoid[]" value="<?php echo $line[id]?>"><?php echo $line['title']?>
```

Means, for multiple checkbox. Use `name` as `array` type. Like `videoid[]`.

**2)** Use `for` or `foreach` loop for inserting multiple checkbox value into a table. First, find out the checked checkbox through `sizeof`. Then, use accordingly.

**Updated Code**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username","$password","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");
$user=$_POST['userid']; 
$videoCheckBox=$_POST['videoid'];  

$checkedVideo = sizeof($videoCheckBox);

for($i=0;$i<$checkedVideo;$i++) {
    $videoId = $videoCheckBox[$i];
    $queryVideo = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `tbl_selection` (`userid`, `videoid`) VALUES ('$user', '$videoId');");  
}

if($checkedVideo == 0) {
    echo'<script>alert("Failed To Insert")</script>';  
} elseif($queryVideo) {
    echo'<script>alert("Inserted Successfully")</script>';
}

?>  
</body>  
</html> 


<div class="control-group">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM video";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <div class="controls"> 
        <label class="checkbox"> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="videoid[]" value="<?php echo $line['id']?>"><?php echo $line['title']?> 
        </label> 
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

For more info, please click [Inserting data into mySQL table from mutlidimensional input form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316831/inserting-data-into-mysql-table-from-mutlidimensional-input-form/32317001#32317001)